# How to bind to a property of a property in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a listview who's itemssource is a ObservableCollection of MyModel.  I am trying to figure how to bind a textbox text's property to the Name property of the model's Owner property

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I tried:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Owner.Name}" />
```

but that leaves the textblock blank.  Whats the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding looks fine. I assume that you put the `TextBlock` into a `DataTemplate` and attached this to the `ListView`. If yes, that should work.

To find the error, replace the `Binding` through a literal to see if you have some rows (The literal must be shown in every line). If not, check the `ItemsSource`. If yes, check that you have really a `Person`-object attached to your `MyModel`-instances and that the `Name`-property is not null or empty. Check also the output window of VS. There you will see binding-errormessages.

If you have no DataTemplate, here an example:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="[Your ItemsSource]">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>                
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Owner.Name}"/>
            </Grid>                    
        </DataTemplate>                
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>                                    
 </ListView>
```

Comment: I am stupid.  I didnt actually have the Name property set as a property I had it as a public member.  Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the DataContext is set properly and implement INotifyPropertyChanged (raise the event it defines when the value of the property changes.).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Data Source Wizard form VS 2010
I just add these classes and click, clik, clik

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="nameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Owner.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Slider  Margin="81,161.66,66,0" Name="Height" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Width="400"></Slider>
<Slider Margin="81,1.66,66,0"  Name="Width" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Width="400"/>
<Ellipse Height="{Binding ElementName=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=Width}"  Fill="Blue" ></Ellipse>
```

Comment: Please consider to [edit] your answer to explain how your answer addresses this 10 year old question in ways that the existing answers do not.